# How to use a slide animation rather than a "ghosting" animation when a UICollectionViewCell changes position due to a change in height of it's parent?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building a UICollectionView which has two cells.  When the user taps a button, the second cell needs to move from directly below the first cell to directly to the right of the first cell (off screen) and allow the user to scroll over to it.

**The kicker is that I need it to appear to slide to the new position.  Using my current code, it's just "ghosting".**

Here's how I'm doing it now:

- Initialize the UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout with horizontal scrolling, paging enabled, and a height of two cells plus margin (196pt * 2 + 8pt = 400pt)

  ```
  func setupTestCollectionView() {

      // Create the layout, the frame, and the collection view

      let testLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
      let testFrame = CGRect()
      let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: testFrame, collectionViewLayout: testLayout)

      // Specify the attributes of the elements we just created and add them to the primary view

      testLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
      testLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
      testLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

      collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
      collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
      collectionView.register(ArtworkCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "artworkCell")
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self

      view.addSubview(collectionView)

      // Set all of the constraints to position the UICollectionView in the primary view then append them to the initialConstraints array

      let topConstraint = collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8)
      let leadingConstraint = collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
      let trailingConstraint = collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
      testHeightConstraint = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)

      // testHeightConstraint is declared outside of this function so we can modify it in a different funcction when the user taps a button

      initialConstraints.append(contentsOf: [topConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, testHeightConstraint])


  }
  ```
- Change the height constraint of the UICollectionView when the user taps a button to a height of 1 cell (196pt) and animate the layout update

  ```
  func testButtonAction() {

      // Change the height constraint of the UICollectionView

      testHeightConstraint.constant = 196

      // Animate the layout update

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }

  }
  ```

This achieves the function I'm looking for (see screenshots below), but so far I've been unable to figure out how to change the animation. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Screenshot on View Load:

[image: Screenshot on View Load]

Screenshot after Button is Tapped:

[image: Screenshot after Button is Tapped]

Screenshot of Scrolling (to show functionality & position):

[image: Screenshot of Scrolling]

Comment: A CollectionView animates its content when its frame changes - such as when you rotate the device. If you don't like the "built-in" animation, you could try writing your own `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass. In this case, however... do you really have only those two cells? Or are you looking at having many cells, and cells 4,5,6 will need to animate from vertical to horizontal?

Comment: I'll look into that for sure...  I definitely only want to have two cells (It's the front and the back of the postcard).  When the user presses a "decline artwork" button, the back of the card will animate to that position.

Comment: If you *are* only using two "cells" then I'd suggest *not* using `UICollectionView` ... just use UIViews and manipulate the constraints.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks DonMag!